# how to check the checkbox already exist

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am inserting check box dynamically.I need to check now if the checkbox with particular value already inserted so that i dont need to insert it again

```
var select = document.getElementById("container2");
               var option = document.createElement("option");
              // alert(value['name']);
                option.text =value['name'];
                option.text=jQuery.trim(option.text);

               option.value=encodeURIComponent(value['name']);






                topics.forEach(function(d)
                              {
                              if (option.text==d.name) {
                                 var radioBtn = $('<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="'+option.text+'" value="'+option.text+'" >'+option.text+'</label></li>');
                                 radioBtn.appendTo('#values');
                              }
                              else if (option.text!==d.name) {
                                   var radioBtn = $('<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="'+option.text+'" value="'+option.text+'" >'+option.text+'</label></li>');
                                  radioBtn.appendTo('#values');
                              }


                              });
```

so here option.text will contain data such as leader,patient and d.name will contain leader so in first condition it will match i will insert a checkbox.If it not match it inserts all the data in option.text as checkbox.so it will again insert leader .How can i check the checkbox value.so that i can avoid replication.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+d.name+"']").length>0)
{
 //check box already exists with d.name as name
}
else
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` as below
HTML

```
<div id="checkboxes">
<input id="chkbx_0" type="checkbox" name="c_n_0" checked="checked" />Option 1
<input id="chkbx_1" type="checkbox" name="c_n_1" />Option 2
<input id="chkbx_2" type="checkbox" name="c_n_2" />Option 3
<input id="chkbx_3" type="checkbox" name="c_n_3" checked="checked" />Option 4
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var name = 'c_n_0';
if ($.find(":checkbox[name=" + name + "]").length) {
    alert('element found');
} else {
    alert('element not found');
}
});
```

update you `if`

```
 if (option.text==d.name && $.find(":checkbox[name="+d.name+"]").length)
```

Check out [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/dRDx6/1/)